# SSD speed in different socket of CPU and chipset

Tags: ssd, cpu, motherboard, pci-express, chipset

If a motherboard chipset (like B760) has x4 DMI version 4.0 which has speed around 8GBps.

And I use a M.2 NVMe PCIe 4.0 x4 SSD (speed around 8Gbps) in a socket which lanes are directly attached to cpu and then another socket which is connected to chipset.

So, will I get max speed of ssd in both socket? As DMI 4.0 x4 speed is 8Gbps so will I not see any performance difference.

Answer (score 1):

When are not heavily using other devices such as SATA or USB, for example connecting a USB 3 SSD, you will probably get close to the full speed of the faster SSD but obviously you cannot move 10GB/s over an 8GB/s link. Most of the time you will get somewhere near the speed of the SSD but may be slightly limited.

That said, you will only be hitting a minor limit, most games and programs cannot use 8GB/s in a sustained fashion and the only time you will see the speed in action will be copying from USB to the NVMe and then you will be limited by it copying from USB through the DMI link to buffers in memory and then back through the DMI link to the NVMe.

There may be some bottlenecking going on using an ultra-modern NVMe with a lower end motherboard.

Answer (score 0):

Processor lanes are faster than chipset lanes, so are meant to be used
by faster devices.

Processor lanes are reserved for graphics card x16 slots
and M.2 slots for high-speed SSDs, in order to move the data without
any bottleneck constraints by the chipset.

Chipset lanes are used for onboard USB, other M.2 and PCIe slots and SATA.
The chipset itself transfers data to the processor via a dedicated
4-lane PCIe bus.
The result is that devices connected via PCIe lanes to the chipset
have a cap on their maximum bandwidth, which is why processor lanes
are used for the faster devices.

For more information, see the article
[Guide to PCIe Lanes: How many do you need for your workload?](https://www.cgdirector.com/guide-to-pcie-lanes/)